# Check that a view is not hidden by another sibling view using Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I would like to check if a view is not hidden by another view. I did not succeed to test this using the classic `isDisplayed` assertion.

In my case I have a view A and a view B inside the same the layout (FrameLayout). And I want to test that the view A is visible to the user.
But I know, that this test should fail, because the view B is totally overlapping the view A.

Layout example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <View android:id="@+id/view_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
    <View android:id="@+id/view_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</FrameLayout/>
```

Test code:

```
onView(
    withId(R.id.view_a)
).check(
    matches(
        isDisplayed()
    )
)
```

As I say before, this test does not fail, even when the view B is totally over the view A.

How can I use espresso to test that my view A is actually visible to the user? For example when view B is moved using `translateX/Y` or hidden in any other way.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#isDisplayingAtLeast(int)

Comment: did you find any solution for this... i also stuck with this problem

Answer (score 2):

In your case is if you are checking if the view is visible but not necessarily displayed on the screen. For this, you can use `withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility)`.

```
onView(matcher).check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)));
```

Comment: This just checks the visibility property. It would not detect if a view was hidden due to another view displaying on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with isCompletelyDisplayed matcher:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_view_A_id))
.check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
```

Comment: `isCompletelyDisplayed` calls `isDisplyaedAtLeast(100)`. Both can account only for the area cropped by parent view ("view's area is not obscured by any parent view and is thus visible to the user."), since they are using `ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect` which works only with the parent view and the children view in question. This unfortunately cannot account for several siblings (e.g. in `FrameLyout`) which may overlap each other.